# Android: App crashes when doing httpclient.execute in AsyncTask

Tags: android

i'm having problems with httpclient. I debugged the app and it crashes when calling execute function. Here's the code:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
GridView mGridView;
Activity mContex;

public MyAsyncTask(Activity contex) {
    this.mContex = contex;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    //fetch data

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("localhost:3000/api/send");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", params[1]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", params[0]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", "male"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("result", "lazy bee"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", "28"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    return "success";
}
}
```

I call MyAsyncTask here, from a fragment and passing the activity:

```
public class SendResultPageFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText name, email;
MyAsyncTask task;

public static SendResultPageFragment newInstance() {
    return new SendResultPageFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_send_result, container, false);

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.result_next_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    name = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
    email = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.email_txt);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    this.task = new MyAsyncTask(getActivity());
    this.task.execute(this.name.getText().toString(), this.email.getText().toString());
    return ;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know the solution ? Thanks

Comment: please provide some error messages.

Comment: `new HttpPost("localhost:3000/api/send");`. You forgot the protocol. So it should be `new HttpPost("http://localhost:3000/api/send");`. But localhost will not do unless the server is on the same device as your app runs. Please tell your setup. What you want to connect with what.

Comment: `and it crashes when calling execute `. Then which exception you did not catch?

Comment: Ok great thanks I totally forgot the protocol !

Answer (score 0):

`new HttpPost("localhost:3000/api/send");` every http request needs to be fully qualified. also do not use local host.Android wont recognize your endpoint that way. I always use ngrok to broadcast to internet. switch to

```
new HttpPost("http://your_domain");
```

also switch to retrofit2, it uses java annotations to compose its request. Highly recommended. here is a great link to start:https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: use ngrok to broad cast a tunnel

Comment: great you cant go wrong with ngrok, because it generates a compete URL to use both http and https.

Comment: @ greenapps what are you saying , ?

Comment: do something like this ngrok http your_port, go to localhost:4040, then there you will see two url, copy the fully qualified path of either the http ot https . then replace the one in android studio.

Comment: ngrok is very useful to visualize the request and response of your routes.